# How to save backups taken with Titanium Backup?

Tags: titanium-backup

I used Titanium Backup to backup an app and its data. I will be flashing my phone with a new ROM/firmware. How do I ensure I can latter recover the backup? I would like to copy the files to the computer but am not sure what to look for. Does anyone know where Titanium Backup stores the backup files and what files to look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Titanium Backup (TiBu) saves the files it has backed up by default on your *internal or device storage*, unless you have specifically pointed it to save on your external SD .
- Saving on *External SD* is the preferred option, since you can do a factory reset or wipe your device as you would do now to flash new ROM
- OP has [confirmed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155221/how-to-save-backups-taken-with-titanium-backup#comment198786_155224)  that the initial directory of backups was in internal SD `/storage/emulated/legacy/TitaniumBackup`

Now it is required to be saved on the *external SD* for transfer to PC

**Steps to create a backup directory on Ext SD and copy the earlier backed files from internal storage**

1. *Menu → Preferences → Backup Settings → Backup folder location* to display the current backup location (in pic below `/storage/0000-0000/moto titanium` is my current back up location, where `0000-0000` is my external SD)
2. *Press <kbd>Back</kbd> key (to jump to parent folder of device) →Create a new folder  → by name Example*
3. Select *Use the Current folder* and on the nest screen accept the prompt *to move all earlier backups to new folder*. (takes some time depending on the number of backups and it may look like app is doing nothing, be patient, it is working)
4. You are done ! To confirm that the location has changed refresh the application by hitting <kbd>Back</kbd> or reload to go to the home screen and see the changed location
5. Now you are set to transfer the files to PC or upload to cloud - ( TiBu also has uploading to cloud options)

Aside, you can set up the frequency of backups by scheduling them . Additional details and steps to schedule [here](http://lifehacker.com/5784857/how-to-set-up-a-fully-automated-app-and-settings-backup-on-android)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Note: An alternate way of specifying a backup folder is shown by OP in [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155221/how-to-save-backups-taken-with-titanium-backup#comment198790_155224). That is also fine but requires to create a folder using a file explorer before and then specifying it.  Method suggested above, reduces one step of using file explorer to create a folder but that's not a big deal

Comment: "Titanium Backup saves the files .. on your SD card, unless you have specifically pointed it to save on your external SD" I didn't know there was an internal SD card :/

Comment: I have resolved the problem and here were my steps. I had to click "storage provider: Filesystem (click to change)" and selected  Ext. SD card, then specify new folder I created with the file explorer. However, by default, the folder does not have permissions to be written to so you must fix that somehow, for example using the app SDFix (reboot required). This part about fixing write permissions may not be applicable to all versions of Android. Also note, I had the error the application isn't responding. Click "wait" as it may take a long process to move existing backups to new location.

Comment: Here I ask how to restore? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155394/how-to-restore-from-titanium-backup-with-file-on-computer

Comment: I prefer to give a few days before accepting an answer in case someone else has other ideas to contribute.

Comment: I am doing this again and still get "this folder is not writable". You mentioned your instructions include a simple way of solving this but I don't see where? As I said, I think it's necessary to download and install an app like SDFix to save to the sd card.

Comment: I am afraid this is a problem specific to your device / OS.  I don't see any references to this in the app help out my usage of app. Sorry, I can't help here