# How to restore from Titanium Backup with file on computer?

Tags: titanium-backup

I flashed new firmware and before doing so backed up apps and data with Titanium Backup. How do I restore? I have the folder on my PC which contains two `.gz` files and a properties file.

Comment: @beeshyams yes, in fact I didn't even have to copy contents from computer to phone. I guess the backup was saved to SD card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple. Copy from PC the entire folder on your external SD or internal storage and name the folder as you wish

1. Use the *Detect* option on TiBu

*Preferences → Folder Location  → Detect → All*

Select *location*, click Use *Current* ( where current is the folder you have copied )

2. [How to restore your backups on a new phone, or after installing a ROM (if you wiped your phone](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-howtos.html)

> 1. Click the Backup/Restore tab
> 2. Click Menu (the button), Batch
>      Click “Restore all missing apps + system data”
> 3. Reboot your phone

**Caution:** If you are restoring on identical device with same ROM step 2 is fine.

For Restoration on other devices , other ROMs/ upgrades (as in your case), doing this will cause **serious problems** as

- What is user app on one ROM may be a system app on another
- ROMs may be "cooked" differently so replacing a system app from different ROM can cause serious problems
- Apps that are device specific e.g., Samsung Planner will not work on a Moto device

In this case, choose *Restore all apps with data* and a menu shows up, where you can de-select what you don't want to restore (like the first few in picture below)

[image]

Comment: Not even mods can give +2 :) Big thumbs-up for including the "Caution remark" and being that detailed! I'm using TiBu for over 5 years now and never checked this out *LOL* (I always have TiBu's storage on external SD, so it finds its config even after firmware flash or on a new device and I never had the need to do the above).

Comment: Some tips for using the “Backup folder location” dialog to manually select a location, if Titanium Backup fails to auto-detect it: **1.** Press the **Back button** to change the current folder to its parent, and tap a folder in the list to make that the current folder. **2.** If your backups are on an **external SD card**, you can find that SD card’s folder within `/storage/`. It may be called `/storage/extSdCard/`, but if not, look for a directory called something like `/storage/5DEC-CC79/`.